# How to use builder pattern to construct a struct which dynamically implements interfaces

Tags: go, interface, builder

I'm trying to use [builder patterns](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern) (borrowed from Java) to allow structs to implement interfaces. For example, I would ideally like this code pattern:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Oner interface {
    One() int
}

type Twoer interface {
    Two() int
}

func main() {
    s := NewObject().
        WithOne(1).
        Build()

    _, ok := s.(Oner)
    fmt.Println(ok) // Prints true

    _, ok = s.(Twoer)
    fmt.Println(ok) // Prints false

    t := NewObject().
        WithOne(1).
        WithTwo(2).
        Build()

    _, ok = t.(Oner)
    fmt.Println(ok) // Prints true

    _, ok = t.(Twoer)
    fmt.Println(ok) // Prints true
}
```

As you could see, the definition of the builder determines what interfaces `s` and `t` implement.

How would one write the function definition of the builder `NewObject()` so the `Build()` method returns a struct which can (possibly) implement a `Oner` and `Twoer`?

---

## Edit:

Here's some clarification on how it's going to be used. I'm constructing a library barring certain structs from being passed into functions if they violate the type safety. For example:

```
type Oner interface {
    One() int
}

type OneAndTwoer interface {
    Oner

    Two() int
}

type Library interface {
    DoSomethingWithOner(Oner)
    DoSomethingWithOneAndTwoer(Twoer)
}
```

Though we can define a function which always constructs a `OneAndTwoer`, my constraints are whenever we construct a `OneAndTwoer`, this takes a lot longer time than just constructing a `Oner`

```
func NewOneAndTwoer() OneAndTwoer {
    // Do some really really complicated logic which takes a lot of time
}

func NewOner() Oner {
    // Do simple logic
}
```

You could imagine how if we have a `Threer`, `Fourer`, etc, this becomes extremely unwieldly, and we have to construct constructors for all possible permutations of attributes.

This is where builder patterns come in handy. Assuming the calculations for `One`, `Two`, etc are independent of each other, we can pick and choose which interface we want to create.

Comment: While this is possible, it violates type safety. That goes against the point of that article. Maybe there's a better approach. Can you provide a more concrete example?

Comment: I do not get the whole point. Interfaces only need to be implicitly implemented - so even when implementing 3 interfaces Aer,Ber and Cer, when passed as Aer, the struct will only be handled as an Aer anyway.

Comment: Clarified the question, take a look.

Comment: "borrowed from Java" - stop right there. Go is very very different from Java, and trying to borrow from Java will lead to a lot of frustration and bad code. Go uses completely different paradigms and idioms from Java. Do not attempt to write Java code in Go.

Comment: @hlin117 Why do you need a single Builder which constructs different structs which match different interfaces? That seems like an anti-pattern. A more concrete example would help. Also be careful about mixing up interfaces and the structs which implement them. `OneAndTwoer` is an interface. You don't construct an interface, you construct a struct which implements that interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, though it feels very clunky.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

type FieldOner interface {
    FieldOne() int
}

type FieldTwoer interface {
    FieldTwo() int
}
```

Set up structs One and Two implementing FieldOner and FieldTwoer respectively.

```
type One struct {
    one int
}

func (f One) FieldOne() int {
    return f.one
}

type Two struct {
    two int
}

func (f Two) FieldTwo() int {
    return f.two
}
```

Create the FieldBuilder which can store both values and whether it has been given each value, plus WithFieldOne and WithFieldTwo.

```
type FieldBuilder struct {
    one int
    has_one bool
    two int
    has_two bool
}

func NewObject() FieldBuilder {
    return FieldBuilder{ has_one: false, has_two: false }
}

func (f FieldBuilder) WithFieldOne(one int) FieldBuilder {
    f.one = one
    f.has_one = true
    return f
}

func (f FieldBuilder) WithFieldTwo(two int) FieldBuilder {
    f.two = two
    f.has_two = true
    return f
}
```

`Build` might return One, Two, or a combination of One and Two. Since it can return multiple things which have nothing in common between them (*a red flag*) it returns an `interface{}`.

```
func (f FieldBuilder) Build() interface{} {
    switch {
    case f.has_one && f.has_two:
        return struct {
            One
            Two
        }{
            One{one: f.one}, Two{two: f.two},
        }
    case f.has_one:
        return One{ one: f.one }
    case f.has_two:
        return Two{ two: f.two }
    }
    panic("Should never be here")
}
```

Because `Build` returns an `interface{}` it's necessary to typecast the result in order to actually use it possibly defeating the whole point of the exercise.

```
func main() {
    s := NewObject().
        WithFieldOne(1).
        Build()

    s1, ok := s.(FieldOner)
    fmt.Println(s1.FieldOne())

    _, ok = s.(FieldTwoer)
    fmt.Println(ok) // Prints false

    t := NewObject().
        WithFieldOne(1).
        WithFieldTwo(2).
        Build()

    t1, ok := t.(FieldOner)
    fmt.Println(t1.FieldOne())

    t2, ok := t.(FieldTwoer)
    fmt.Println(t2.FieldTwo())
}
```

This does not scale particularly well. Two interfaces require three cases. Three will require six. Four will require ten. Five will need fifteen...